# A word for someone who gives easy answers

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I asked my friend to recommend to me a good movie to watch and he answers with a very cult movie. Or I ask him a metaphoric question but he answers with a common response. He doesn't think nor ponder. He replies with the most popular/obvious answer.

What can we call this kind of person or this situation?

More info Edit: He always responses with the obvious answers unintentionally. He has no class and he is just like ignorant to give advices about the subject

Edit2: maybe some people think "why are you asking a question to someone you think cannot answer it, someone you try to describe ignorant about the subject". I am asking because i think he might know but his answer was very very obvious. So, i should call him with a 'word' and then maybe he become aware of the situation

Comment: If he answers like most would answer, then he is *normal*, or at worst, *ordinary*. If you want a particular connotation, can you provide more specifics?

Comment: jxh, 'ordinary' is ok but i feel like i am looking for another one

Comment: Replying to a metaphoric question with a popular/obvious answer suggests a _conventional_ person; but replying to a request for a movie suggestion with the name of "a very cult movie" suggests that a subset of full-bore conventionality is at work—namely, _predictability_ within a constellation of fixed interests. Perhaps the most accurate term for such a person's answers is _reflexive_, since they come not from any considered thought at the time the question is asked but, as it were, from a database of prepackaged responses available at the press of a mental button.

Comment: Sven, 'conventional' seemed pretty good answer to me. Thank you! Also, i remembered that 'cliche' may be a good word to describe his 'answer'. Thanks again!

Comment: @user107033 Another word to describe his answers might be "facile."

Answer (score 2):

I'd opt for *glib*.

As Merriam-Webster has it

> **glib** adjective \ˈglib\
>   : said or done too easily or carelessly : showing little preparation or thought
>   : speaking in a smooth, easy way that is not sincere

and from OED

> 2. Of an action, method, procedure: Easy, meeting no obstruction; off-hand.
> 3. Of a speaker or writer, of the tongue, etc.: ‘Well-oiled’, ready and fluent in utterance.
>      Of language: Characterized by fluency and readiness. Chiefly in contemptuous use, implying lack of thought or of sincerity.

Particularly the last sentence in *OED 3* above.

---

<sub>"Glib." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 22 Jan. 2015. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glib</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for [vapid](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vapid).

> : not lively or interesting : dull or boring

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how widespread this is, but I've always referred to this type of person (and response) as LCD (lowest common denominator). (US)

Answer (score -1):

If you feel you're not being taken seriously, you might describe the person as [*flippant* (Google def'n)](https://www.google.ca/search?q=define:flippant):

> flippant :
>       not showing a serious or respectful attitude.

Comment: No, i mean he answers like a pleb

Comment: @user107033 I'm not sure what you mean. Please edit your question to add in more information.

Comment: Okay, i edited now

Answer (score -1):

[ill-considered](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ill-considered) -- lacking thorough consideration; ill-suited; unwise.

Definition taken from dictionary.com

Comment: you're right, it would

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps, [**repartee**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/repartee), noun - conversation in which  clever statements and replies are made quickly.
*(TFD)*

Origin : 
French repartie, from repartir to retort, from Middle French, from re- + partir to divide.

But when you say,"he has no class "- it is evocative of a [**lowbrow**](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/lowbrow).